# vim autocommand on buffer load/file open?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, autocmd

I'm trying to execute an autocommand when a file (buffer?) is opened in vim that will display indentation guides by executing `<Leader>ig`. I'm using the vundle plugin `nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides`

I currently am trying `autocmd BufWinEnter <Leader> ig`, but that doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried with `<Leader>ig`.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

vim-indent-guides provides the `:IndentGuidesEnable` function. You can execute this each time you open a file by adding the following to your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre * :IndentGuidesEnable
```

Comment: There's also `BufReadPost` and `FileReadPost` if you want to make sure the file's contents have been read first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add normal mode command to autocmd, you could use `normal` or `exec` like:

```
autocmd SomeEvent exec 'normal ' . (exists('mapleader')?mapleader:'\') . 'ig'
```

I didn't test above line, should work for your case.

Better way I think is, find out what does `<Leader>ig` mapped to, it could be a function, call the function in your autocmd.